# Where could I find web designers/ web developers that would like to work together?

Tags: web-development, website-design

Note: *If this isn't the right place, please let me know where I should ask this.*

I am working on projects to earn money (in codecanyon and themeforest) and I wanted to know for a while where I could talk and find people in those niches.

Are there any sites or forums I should seek? Maybe this could be the right place?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Pro Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Questions of this nature are better suited to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and to forums (there are many established webmaster/dev forums).